# Conditional Binding for Optionals

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code and it complains about the as! keyword. If I replace with as? it works fine.

[image]

Comment: [Swift Language Guide: The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do force unwrapping in `guard` or `if let`. Use optionals. The end product which is `name` in your case is already an unwrapped value for you.

Replace **as!** with **as?**